# Google sheets script to copy text referenced by hyperlinks from one sheet into another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a row of cells in a sheet some of which contain hyperlinks. These hyperlinks reference cells/cell ranges in that same sheet which contain text. I would like to run a script which looks at the range of cells containing the hyperlinks, extracts the text from the cells the hyperlinks reference and paste that text into a column of cells in a new sheet. Chat GPT provided the following code after numerous failed attempts:

```
function copyLinkedText() {
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Marcus Nature Calendar Gannt Master");
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Hyperlinked Flag Text");

    var rangeWithHyperlinks = sourceSheet.getRange("O8:NP8");
    var values = rangeWithHyperlinks.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
            var formula = values[i][j];
            if (formula !== '') {
                var parts = formula.match(/'([^']+)'/);
                if (parts && parts.length >= 2) {
                    var linkedSheetName = parts[1];
                    var linkedCell = parts[2];
                    var linkedText = sourceSheet.getRange(linkedSheetName + '!' + linkedCell).getValue();
                    targetSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setValue(linkedText);
                }
            } else {
                targetSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setValue('');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code executes without errors but no data is extracted from the source sheet and transferred to the target sheet. I suspect it is a problem with the format used for the hyperlinks (?) - they are not in formula format but appear like this eg. 'SheetName'!A16:A24. This is what I see when I hover the mouse over the cell containing the hyperlink.

Can anyone please help me achieve what I'm trying to do ? Thanks in advance. BTW I'm a scripting noob, hence my reliance on Chat GPT.

I tried the code above which ran without errors but did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: use `getRichTextValues()`

The code recommended by Chat GPT won't work in your case as the links were not inserted via a formula. Do correct me if I'm wrong but I assume you've used the [`Get link to this cell`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErRg1.png) option to get the hyperlink to the cell.

### **EDIT:**

After checking the demo spreadsheet, it appears that the links were created using this [method](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?hl=en#zippy=%2Clink-to-a-range-of-cells-in-a-spreadsheet). The links created references a range ID, similar to named ranges, instead of the exact location of the cells/ranges. Using a slightly modified version of [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)'s excellent [workaround](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3aa69f1a8e2a944c7df926879fa0f34e), I was able to retrieve the texts from the cells referenced by the hyperlinks.

Do try this code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen(e) {
  const range = e.source.getActiveRange(); //gets the location of the referenced cell/range from the dialog box
  CacheService.getScriptCache().put( //caches the location.
    "range",
    JSON.stringify({
      sheetName: range.getSheet().getSheetName(),
      a1Notation: range.getA1Notation(),
    })
  );
}

//Make sure to run this function
function openRange(e) {
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Stack Demo Hyperlinked Text'); //Replace this with the name of the source sheet if needed.
  var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange('A8:NI8').getRichTextValues().flat(); //Gets the rich text value of the range. Adjust the range if needed.
  var linkValues = [] // Array to store the texts inside the cells referenced by the links.

  sourceValues.forEach(x => {
    //Loops through each cell on the row and gets the link URL
    var linkUrl = x.getLinkUrl();
    if (linkUrl != null) { 
      //Opens a dialog box to capture the value of the reference cells if there's a valid URL
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/edit${linkUrl}"></iframe>`);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Capturing cell values...');

      Utilities.sleep(10000); //Pauses the script for 10 seconds to allow the dialog box to load
      const text = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('range'); //Retrieves the cached location of the referenced cell/range
      if (!text) throw new Error("Range couldn't be retrieved.");
      const { sheetName, a1Notation } = JSON.parse(text);

      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<script>google.script.host.close();</script>'`);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Closing...'); //Closes the dialog box.
      html.clear(); //Clears the HTML output.

      console.log(`'${sheetName}'!${a1Notation}`); //Logs the location of the referenced cell/range on the console for checking. Feel free to remove this.
      const range = ss.getRange(`'${sheetName}'!${a1Notation}`); //Gets the range(s) of the reference cell(s)
      linkValues.push(range.getValues());
    }
  })
  CacheService.getScriptCache().remove('range'); //clears the cache.
  copyReferenceValues(linkValues) //Runs the function that inserts the captured values to the destination sheet.
}

function copyReferenceValues(linkValues) {
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hyperlinked Flag Text'); //Replace this with the name of the target sheet if needed.
  linkValues = linkValues.flat();
  var maxColumn = Math.max(...linkValues.map(i => i.length));//Gets the number of columns of the largest range captured.
  linkValues.forEach(y => { //Adds blank elements to the array to ensure that each row has the same size.
    while (y.length < maxColumn) {
      y.push('');
    }
  });

  /*
  The last part of the code below inserts the texts to the target sheet.
  Do note that you would have to adjust the range if needed.
  */
  destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, linkValues.length, maxColumn).setValues(linkValues);
  return;
}
```

I've confirmed that this script works in the demo spreadsheet. However, please note of the following:

- *Only* run the `openRange` function.
- Apps Scripts have a maximum runtime of 6 minutes. Using the script above, you would only be able to retrieve the text of a maximum of 36 cells/ranges referenced by hyperlinks.
- To retrieve the link from all 300 hyperlinks, you would have to run the the script in batches by modifying the range declared in `sourceValues`
- For larger ranges referenced by the hyperlinks, you may need to increase the value inside `Utilities.sleep()`.
- The script assumes that the hyperlinks were all inserted the same way.
- There's currently no direct way of retrieving the location of the cell/range from the range ID via Apps Script. Opening the hyperlink on a dialog box appears to be the best option for now.
- There's an existing [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129841094) similar to this. However, considering that the request has been open for more than 4 years, we can't expect Google to implement it anytime soon.

### References:

- [Tanaike's GitHub post detailing the workaround](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3aa69f1a8e2a944c7df926879fa0f34e)
- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [getLinkUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getlinkurl)
- [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)
- [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

Comment: Thanks so much DuuEyn. Sadly this doesn't work. Each cell contains an "X" checkmark. Then I inserted a link using the Google Sheets menu item "insert link" and added the cell reference for the link to point to. Any script I try appears to have a problem accessing that cell reference that the link is pointing to. Chat GPT is now suggesting I do it manually. 300 of them. Lol. That situation where the time you use up trying to save time by automating the function you really could have used inputting the data manually.... :-) Appreciate any other ideas you might have. Thanks.

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate. Would you be able to share a [demo spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383) showing how the links are configured so that I or other community members can further look into it?

Comment: Sure. Here is a link to a demo sheet with examples of the hyperlinks. Thanks. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uo92nnGXO2876MHtxHsuHVgn1p0j0QVhHknNFHhCS68/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the demo sheet. I've updated the answer with a new code. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That's great DuuEyn ! Thank you very much - you've saved me a *lot* of time. I can work with the batch limit, no problem. I'll run it on the full sheet once complete. 10 batch runs should do it.

Comment: You're welcome Zeropoint! Feel free to accept or upvote my answer (by clicking the relevant button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that there's a possible workaround.

Comment: I haven't got sufficient privileges to upvote but I've accepted your answer. Thanks again DuuEyn.